# Complementarity on sum of Banach spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, we can select a norm for which $Z=X \oplus Y$ is a Banach space as well. My question has two parts:

1) If $M$ and $N$ are complementary subspaces in $X$ and $Y$, respectively, that is there exist closed subspaces $M_1 \subset X$ and $N_1 \subset Y$ such that $X=M\oplus M_1$ and $Y=N \oplus N_1$, is $M \oplus N$ a complementary subspace of $X\oplus Y$ ? (In my opinion it is, and it's complement is $M_1 \oplus N_1$)

2) If $V$ is a complementary subspace of $X\oplus Y$, and it's components in $X$ and, respectively $Y$ complementary subspaces ? By that I mean, we can decompose $V$ as $V=V_x \oplus V_y$, where $V_x \subset X$ and $V_y \subset Y$, are $V_x$ and $V_y$ subspaces of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, and are they closed, and if they are closed, are they complementary ( $V_x$ complementary in $X$ and $V_y$ complementary in $Y$)? (I think they are closed subspaces, but the complementarity part I'm not so sure)

Comment: Where do you have problems to prove 1)? Concerning 2): Think about the diagonal $V=\lbrace (x,x): x\in\mathbb R\rbrace$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I didn't, just wanted to check with others. Thank you for the counterexample.